# Collapsible section/region in Javascript (Visual Studio 2010 / 2012)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I came across this [link](http://blog.degree.no/2013/05/define-a-region-in-javascript-files-visual-studio-2010-2012/) that allows you to define collapsible sections in javascript, without any Visual Studio Extensions or Macros. Although you automatically get outlining while defining functions, but the link discusses a shortcut to make any javascript code, collapsible.

By using **Ctrl+M+H**, while selecting javascript code, you can get the collapsible section.

**The question is, how do you undo that? Ctrl+M+U does not work.**

**You can remove all the outlining for the entire document using Ctrl+M+P, but how can you undo the outlining for a single section only?**

Comment: Does it toggle? Will pressing it again while highlighting that section expand it?

Comment: Yes it toggles, by clicking on the + plus. But not by pressing Ctrl+M+H again

Comment: I my VS2010, when I press Ctrl+M+H it collapses into 3 little dots. Double clicking the dots re-expanded the section.

Comment: Ok. Is that what you needed? Or are you looking for another behavior?

Comment: I want to remove the + sign

Comment: @HassanFahim I found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2010, the options for this are under Edit >> Outlining

As you know, press Ctrl+M, Ctrl+H to create an outlining section.

With the section highlighted, press Ctrl+M, Ctrl+U to stop the current selection, and Ctrl+M then Ctrl+P to stop highlighting all.

Also you can use the options in the menu, or the shortcut keys.

Comment: @Skyhawk I downvoted before you before you removed the "no way to do this in VS"